# Hazelcast Kubernetes discovery - pods not discovering each other when application starts

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm trying to configure Hazelcast caching cluster with Spring boot using Kubernetes API discovery strategy and having an issue when application starts:
The pods are booting up just fine but only discovering themselves. The logs show:

```
[XXX.XXX.XXX.61]:5701 [dev] [4.2.8] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [XXX.XXX.XXX.61]:5701 - 91542a2e-9e46-4c91-ae21-4ddec9bf7956 this
]
```

and

```
[XXX.XXX.XXX.2]:5701 [dev] [4.2.8] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [XXX.XXX.XXX.2]:5701 - a9239765-a249-4c9a-92e6-4a9b34995b1d this
]
```

When killing one pod it works just fine and see:

```
[XXX.XXX.XXX.185]:5701 [dev] [4.2.8] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [XXX.XXX.XXX.185]:5701 - 49b5660c-5484-4567-8d5b-8ff2adba5853 this
    Member [XXX.XXX.XXX.61]:5701 - 5701 - 91542a2e-9e46-4c91-ae21-4ddec9bf7956
]
```

It seems like there's some kind of race condition.

Is there anyway to solve it this?

Comment: Do you have a stateful set ? `podManagementPolicy` unset or `OrderedReady` ?

Comment: Also, worth trying a newer version of Hazelcast

Comment: What config are you using?

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestions! After leaving it overnight I saw that it just needed some time. both pods discovered themselves but then merged to 1 cluster